# Apache JMeter with IntelliJ and jmeter-maven-plugin

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I want to run a jmeter script using IntelliJ and Maven. Basicaly my goal is to run a jmeter script thru Jenkins. 
**I did following steps:**

1. Downloaded Jmeter source code and extracted all files under
   **C:\Jmeter\apache-jmeter-3.3**
2. Created a script by launching jmeter using **jmeter.bat**
3. Saved the script under **C:\Jmeter\apache-jmeter-3.3\bin\templates\create-client.jmx**
4. Created a new Maven Project in IntelliJ under new folder **C:\Jmeter-test**
5. Copied report-template, reportgenerator.properties under **src/test/resources**
6. Copied **create-client.jmx** under **src/test/jmeter/create-client.jmx**
7. Modifiled **pom.xml** to include Jmeter plugin

   ```
   <plugins>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
           <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>1.6.1</version>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>jmeter</goal>
                   </goals>
               </execution>
           </executions>
           <configuration>
               <testFilesIncluded>
                   <jMeterTestFile>create-client.jmx</jMeterTestFile>

               </testFilesIncluded>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
   ```

When i run **mvn verify** command, it sayd 'No Tests to Run'. I am not very familiar with IntelliJ and Maven. Not sure if i need to import existing Jmeter souce code.Any help would be appreaciated. Thanks!

Comment: put the script in <Project Dir>/src/test/jmeter

Comment: @KirilS. have the script under C:\Jmeter-test\src\test\jmeter\create-client.jmx and still mvn verify output is 'No Tests to run'

Comment: once again, scripts should be in project directory, under src/test/jmeter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per this documentation :

- https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Selecting-Tests-To-Run#2

Use version **2.7.0** and it should be ok:

```
     <plugin>
    <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>jmeter-tests</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jmeter</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <testFilesIncluded>
            <jMeterTestFile>create-client.jmx</jMeterTestFile>

        </testFilesIncluded>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```